# How can I populate the basepath of a swagger document when I have multiple versions of my API?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, api-versioning

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to generate my swagger document, and I am using [ApiVersion](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) to version my controllers. My setup supports multiple versions, and this works fine. Meaning I can select a version in the Swagger UI, and I have a swagger document created for each of my versions, with only the relevant actions.

However, I would like to refactor the swagger documents in order to make better use of the basepath-property.

As an example, let me use the swagger document generated for version 1 of my API. In this document, all the paths begin with `"/api/v1/..."`, and there is no basepath in the generated swagger document. However, what I *would* like, is for all my paths to simply begin with `"/..."`, and that the generated document includes a basepath property with the value `"/api/v1"`.

I have tried creating a DocumentFilter, which gets me close, but not all the way. True, I can access the `GroupName` property (which holds the version-string "v1"), but my predicate obviously fails, since the value of `swaggerDoc.Info.Version` is "1.0". This is how the class looks today:

```
public class SetBasePath : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.BasePath = $"/{context.ApiDescriptionsGroups.Items.Where(i => i.GroupName == swaggerDoc.Info.Version).Single().GroupName}";
    }
}
```

Then I tried another approach, using `PreSerializeFilters` to first add the basepath to the swagger document, and then removing it again from the paths in the document. This also got me very close, but failed since `PreSerializeFilters`is not executed for each of the swagger documents, but once (and hence the last basepath specified will be used in all the generated documents). This is my code using `PreSerializeFilters`:

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        var basepath = $"/api/{description.GroupName}";

        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
        {
            swaggerDoc.Host = httpReq.Host.Value;
            swaggerDoc.BasePath = basepath;
        });

        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
        {
            IDictionary<string, PathItem> paths = new Dictionary<string, PathItem>();
            foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
            {
                paths.Add(path.Key.Replace(basepath, string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCulture), path.Value);
            }
            swaggerDoc.Paths = paths;
        });
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me walk that last mile, and get this working the way I'd like?

Comment: Do you have your project on GitHub?

Comment: Nope, sorry. But aspnet-api-versioning has a few sample projects that could be used as a starting point, for example this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can make the ApiDescription objects match the Swagger document version. You cannot safely reverse the Swagger document version; however, since you are in control of creating it to begin with, it's not hard to match. You are likely using the example behavior, which looks like:

```
new Info() { Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString() }
```

Using the provided extension methods, you can match this in your document filter like so:

```
public class SetBasePath : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var docVersion = swaggerDoc.Info.Version;
        var groupName = (from descriptionGroup in context.ApiDescriptionGroups.Items
                         from description in descriptionGroup.Items
                         let apiVersion = description.GetApiVersion().ToString()
                         where apiVersion == docVersion
                         select descriptionGroup.GroupName).First();

        swaggerDoc.BasePath = "/api/" + groupName;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Although I had to change from group to itemgroup in the query for the code to compile. You may want to edit your anser in case someone tries to copy-paste it ;)